# How to open more modals in same page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like two buttons to open a modal and two more to open another but I can't get it to work.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.pack.detail');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

[].forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
  var id = el.id;
  alert(id);
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}


var modal = document.getElementById('modal2');
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.pack.detail');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

[].forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
  var id = el.id;
  alert(id);
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Modal */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Content */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {
 padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="pack detail" id="1">Open modal 1</button>
<button class="pack detail" id="2">Open modal 2</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="modal-header">
   <span class="close">&times</span>
   <h2>Modal Header</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- Body -->
  <div class="modal-body">
   <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
   <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="modal-header">
   <span class="close">&times</span>
   <h2>Modal Header2</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- Body -->
  <div class="modal-body">
   <p>Some text in the Modal Body2</p>
   <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <h3>Modal Footer2</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why the second modal opens anyway. I need it to open a different modal for each button with id generated by a mysql database. I have already seen many other posts but I can't adapt them to my needs. Please without Bootstrap.

Comment: Did you intentionally double your javascript code?

Comment: @jstarnate it looks like OP was trying to replicate the code, but base the second code using the `2` ids. I added an answer that avoids all that unnecessary doubling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has to do with how you are trying to reuse the variable names `modal`, `btns` and `span`. You could rename those variables...however, you can also make your code way more efficient.

I basically set the id of the first modal to include the #1. So now, we can use the `id` of the button to add to call the correct modal.

I commented all the lines.

```js
// get all the buttons
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.pack.detail');
// get all the close spans
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span.close');

// using your original forEach
[].forEach.call(btns, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
    // Get the button id.
    var id = el.id;
    // Get the modal using the modal ID AND the button id.
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal' + id);
    // Now we display the correct modal.
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
});

// All the close spans
[].forEach.call(span, function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
    // Get the closest parent with the class .modal
    var current_modal = el.closest('.modal');
    // set the display to none.
    current_modal.style.display = "none";
  }
});

// on window click, if the target has the class modal.
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.className == 'modal') {
    // close the modal that's open.
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Modal */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Content */

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="pack detail" id="1">Open modal 1</button>
<button class="pack detail" id="2">Open modal 2</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times</span>
      <h2>Modal Header2</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body2</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. What if you want to .append() something based on the id?

Comment: What would you like to append? Also, if this answers your question, please up vote and mark as accepted. I can then edit to include the `append` functionality

Comment: I would like to have a modal to view a group of users, a modal to view the books read by a given user and a modal for reporting and they must coexist on the same page. The extraction part is already written, my problem lies in bringing together the three different modes and choosing the right one based on the chosen button. Sorry for my english 

Comment: Ah..that's a bigger question than an edit. I would mark this answer as accepted, since it answers the original question. Then open up a new question with what you want do, with this updated code, since you will need to add more detail about the extraction/data par (users, books and reporting). Your English is great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dynamicity to avoid repeating code since you said that you're getting your buttons' ids from the database. For that to work, each of your button's id must match the id of the modal that it tries to open.

**HTML**

```
<button class="pack detail" id="1">Open modal 1</button>
<button class="pack detail" id="2">Open modal 2</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close" data-modal='modal1'>&times</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
            <p>Some other text...</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close" data-modal='modal2'>&times</span>
            <h2>Modal Header2</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the Modal Body2</p>
            <p>Some other text...</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.pack.detail');
var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

btns.forEach(function(el) {
  el.onclick = function() {
    var id = el.id;
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal' + id);

    alert(id);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
})

spans.forEach(function(span) {
  span.onclick = function(event) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.modal);
    modal.style.display = "none";    
  }
})

window.onclick = function(event) {
    var modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```